# Using Night Mode in AVFoundation in Swift

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avkit

Is there a way to make use of the Night Mode feature on iPhone 11s and 12s in camera applications using `AVFoundation`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be available to developers yet—as are the other computational photography features like Smart HDR, Portrait, or Panorama.

Hopefully, we get some access to the processing pipeline when ProRAW ships later this year.

Comment: Ok, thank you! If you ever find any updates, let us know! I'll do the same